# Unable to change the value of Filtered data length in angular4

Tags: html, angular

I want to change the count of the filterdata [i.e. `[(ngModel)]="filterdata"`]  after the data has arrived in the tables. For Example:

[image]

Initially in the text-box, i entered "experia" so all the data from the database that has experia appeared in the table. And the number of data is displayed on the right-hand  of the table as you can see in the picture => "Number of searched data = 6". However, the issue is, if i enter text again in the search-text box and the data filters, but this filtered data number is not displayed, like "Number of searched data =4", of course this number will be less than the maximum number i.e.=6.It remains the same as >> "Number of searched data = 6" even though the total data displayed number is 4.

I have used an (ngModelChange) because i thought it might work, but it doesn't.

code:

**transaction.component.html**

```
  <input class="form-control" id="input1-group1" style="margin- 
   top:20px" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter Search Text"
              [(ngModel)]="filterdata"  (ngModelChange)= 
    "countFilter(filterdata)"(keyup.enter)="searchByText(filterdata)">

 //code

  <h2> Transaction  </h2>
  <label *ngIf="toShowCount" id="arrayCountId"> Number of searched 
  data  : {{arrayCount}}</label>
```

**transaction.component.ts**

```
  countFilter(filtData){

   console.log("inside countFilter = "+ filtData)
    this.countFilterData = filtData.length;

    if(this.arrayCount>=0){

   if(this.countFilterData<this.arrayCount){


    var result = [];
    var url = config.url;
    var port = config.port;

    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
   "/transaction/masterSearchTransactionForm/", this.filterObj
    , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
     localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
    .map(result => this.result = result.json())
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    console.log("# DATE FILTER RESULT TRANSACTION  XXXXXXXXXXXX", 
     res);
     this.records = res;

     this.toShowCount =true;
      console.log ("the result of SearchByText is =  ", this.result)
     this.arrayCount = this.result.length;
     console.log("ArrayCount = " , this.arrayCount)
     console.log("search-by-text  records = ",res)

      console.log("Search by Text result is : " + result)
      if (this.result.length > 0) {

      this.notify.Success("Data Displayed Successfully");
      this.loading = false;

       }
       else {
        this.notify.Error("No Matching Data Available")

        this.loading = false;

       }
      });


     }
    }
```

Comment: This way: `(ngModelChange)="countFilter(filterdata)"` you pass old `filterdata` value, looks like you have to pass the new one from event, like this: `(ngModelChange)="countFilter($event)"`

Comment: @Commercial suicide .. i tried, but no difference in the answer. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (ngModelChange)="countFilter(filterdata)" because as i can see you have 2 methods that call REST endpoint for filtering data: one in countFilter(filterdata) and the other one in searchByText(filterdata). When you call searchByText(filterdata) i presume that you are trying to filter data on server and get results. When you get that result from server, than you put length of that result in variable like you did in countFilter method.

```
 this.arrayCount = this.result.length;
```

just put this in searchByText method and remove countFilter because you do not need it.

EDIT:

```
<input class="form-control" id="input1-group1" style="margin- 
   top:20px" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter Search Text"
   #searchControl (keyup.enter)="searchByText(searchControl.value)"
   (input)="countFilter($event.target.value)"       
>
```

in your .ts file you will have a method searchByText(value) that calls API endpoint and query data table, something like this:

```
searchByText(value) {
    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
    "/transaction/masterSearchTransactionForm/", this.filterObj
    , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
    localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
    .map(result => this.result = result.json())
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.records = res;
}
```

Now , you have saved all data that you queried first time with ENTER click
After this you want to have method that can filter through this saved data:

```
countFilter(value) {
    this.records = this.records.filter((record) => record.name == value);
}
```

now you have a same variable (this.records) with filtered data! And in html you can just do string interpolation {{this.records.length}}

Comment: Hi Milos, yeah you are correct, i got the length from this.arrayCount=this.result.length... this got the length of the display data...now i again filter this data  and that second filter count i want

Comment: But i don't see the difference: first time when you are quering the data base table of let's say 1000 records, you get let's say 15 matches! The second time when you query the database table you again query 1000 records and get 23 matches! You are always calling the same API endpoint and query the same table am i right?

Comment: but i donot press the enter key ...when i press the enter key again..then i will get 23 matches !

Comment: So this is what you want: when you query database table with ENTER key you are calling searchByText(filterdata) and then you want to query that result set that you got from first api call ? You want to query that result set with (ngModelChange)="countFilter(filterdata)" ?

Comment: Yes... exactly ..do you know any way ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please take a look and see if anything is helpful to you!